# how can i change the color of the text in the tag depending on the value

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I use ajax technology, I want to send values to the div tag, but depending on the values that are in the table. I think a cycle is necessary here, but how to do it right?

I use xampp. backend php.

**index.php**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button" 
    onclick="taskphp()">Tapşırıqlar</a>
</li>
```

**javascript.js**

```
function taskphp() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            let state = document.getElementById("state");
            let stateValue = document.getElementById("state").innerHTML;
            switch(stateValue) {
                case "duzelib":
                state.style.color = "green";
                break;
                case "duzelme prosesinde":
                state.style.color = "yellow";
                break;
                case "duzelmeyib":
                state.style.color = "red";
                break;
                default:
                state.style.color = "white";
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "IT/tasks.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

**tasks.php**

```
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo  "<tbody><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row["task"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["description"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["task_objects"]."</td>";
    echo "<td id=\"state\">".$row["state"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["entrance_date"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["execute_date"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["source"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["month"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr></tbody>";
}
?>
```

I using switch, I was able to change the color of only the first element in the list, and I need to change the colors of all elements depending on their value

Comment: As your issue is around the code running on the browser, show us the rendered HTML, not the code which created it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of things you need to keep in mind.

The way you've set this up, you'll end up with a bunch of elements that have the id "state". Now in theory, an id should be unique to a single HTML element. That's why we have `getElementById` but not `getElementsbyId`.

You know what can be shared among multiple elements? Classes! So first thing you want to do is change your php so that

```
echo "<td id=\"state\">".$row["state"]."</td>";
```

becomes

```
echo "<td class=\"state\">".$row["state"]."</td>";
```

So now all the elements of type 'state' can be retrieved as an array using `getElementsByClassName`. Then you can loop through that array then run your switch statement on each 'state' element individually:

```
const states = document.getElementsByClassName("state");
for (const state of states) {
    const stateValue = state.innerHTML;
    switch(stateValue) {
        case "duzelib":
            state.style.color = "green";
            break;
        case "duzelme prosesinde":
            state.style.color = "yellow";
            break;
        case "duzelmeyib":
            state.style.color = "red";
            break;
        default:
            state.style.color = "white";
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes! It turned out as he wanted. Thank you very much)